# Android layout gravity center horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gravity

I have a problem with `android:layout_gravity="center"` in `LinearLayout`. I put text in the top and when I want to move it to the top center he moves it to the center of the phone and not to the up center.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:background="@drawable/c19669a65794159b935e89fac1d08080"
    tools:context="com.example.hanan.myfirstapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Exemple"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` instead of `android:layout_gravity="center"` in the inner view.

The value `center` affects both axis, while you want to work only on the X one.

You can find more details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity).